# 19th history mathematics puzzle

Tags: math-history

Consider the following fictitious conversation between 19th century mathematicians:

Teddy: This new field of calculus seems valid, but in some ways it’s sketchy. It
needs to have a sound foundation like geometry does.

George: You’re right. Euclid was the bomb! Let’s get on that.

Johnny: But wait, what’s so special about calculus? I know it’s “The Calculus”
and all, but shouldn’t every field have such a strong foundation?

Joe: Yeah, Johnny is right. I’m a number theorist and we’ve been following
Euclid, Pythagoras, Diophantus, and Fibonnacci blindly! What if there’s
something wrong with number theory?

Johnny: Exactly! And algebra? What if Cardano, Tartaglia, and Bombelli based
their work on faulty assumptions?

Teddy: We’re gonna need help.

Apparently each character represents a different relevant 19th century mathematician. The names of the characters are hints to the mathematicians actual names.

I am completely stuck...I thought Gauss was George just because he is the prince of mathematics.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does this come from? What's the source?

Comment: A math history course I am taking.

Comment: Perhaps the facts that those 19-th century mathematicians consider calculus as a "new field" back then and they all speak english are hints...:)

Comment: Teddy is (Karl Theodor Wilhelm) Weierstrass

Comment: Calculus "new" in the 19'th century?  It's a product of the 17'th!

Comment: @smcc how do you know/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Weierstrass#Soundness_of_calculus

Comment: You are describing "the foundational crisis of mathematics."  David Hilbert was the champion to formally revisit the underlying axiomatic systems.  Important players include Bertrand Russel, Gotleib Freige, Guiseppe Peano,  Gregor Cantor....And the process fell on its head, when Kurt Goedel came along.

Comment: I think Joe might be Joseph-Louis Lagrange.

Comment: Johnny could be Hilbert since he was so concerned with formalizing all of mathematics with Hilbert's program.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I thought that, but I didn't know how he is connected to the name Johnny?

Comment: Johnny could be Gauss, because his full name was Johann Carl Friedrich Gauss. Joseph-Louis Lagrange was Italian (but he died rather early in the 19th century). Another Italian who could be "Johnny" or "Joe" is Giuseppe Peano.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that George is Georg Cantor, and I am positive that Joe is Guissepe Peano.

smcc suggest Weierstrass is Teddy, and that is plausible.  By the way Calculus was always thought to be on a shaky foundation.  Cauchy, Bolzano, Riemann and Weierstrass built the foudations of calculus 100 years after Liebnitz.

I am still scratching my head about who Johnny might be.

Comment: How do you know Joe is Guissepe Peano?

Comment: He was a number theorist who wrote the axioms of arithmetic.

Comment: The second given name of Karl Weierstrass is Theodor, making it virtually certain he is Teddy.